# Is there any way to find out how Microsoft SSMS is creating queries (code) from views?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Basically I want to know what SSMS is doing behind the scenes when you right click on a view -> script view as -> create to -> new query editor window/ file/ clipboard.

Comment: Pulls the definition of the view from the database and copies it to your clipboard?

Comment: I'm guessing what you are really is asking is what is the logic the engine is doing to produce the code? If you want to see that in action you can use profiler. Just clear it out right before you script your view. Then sit back and realize there is a ton of stuff going on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL Server Profiler to intercept the SQL: create a new trace; use event selection to remove unwanted data; start and stop to inspect the SQL, i.e.:

1. Click New Trace
2. Use the template: Tuning
3. Click Run

   —on the events selection: uncheck rpc: completed, sp:StmtCompleted

   filter for your query:

   1. click column filter
   2. DatabaseName like "abcDatabase"

   see (https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/raj1979/how-to-use-sql-server-profiler-and-tuning-advisor/)